# Using a bottle API on python causes an error when passing arguments into functions

Tags: python, bottle

I'm writing an API in python using the bottle library but I'm having an issue.

When I run the following code:

```
from bottle import route, run
apiArray = ["key0","key1","key2"]
@route('/<userApi>/')
def hello(userApi,apiArray):
    for item in apiArray:
        if item == userApi:
            return {True}
    return {False}
run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

When I run that code though I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1732, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
TypeError: hello() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong and why I am getting this error?

Comment: Why did you put `apiArray` as an argument to the function?

Comment: @BrenBarn Because I need that array in the function.

Comment: @BrenBarn How would I get that array into the function otherwise?

Comment: You defined it as a global variable, so it's available everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you passing in `apiArray` if it's a variable already declared?? The function takes two variables but that route will only ever receive one. Remove this and it should work. It's in context so it's not needed but if you needed to pass it in as an argument, you should add it to the route. Otherwise it would never be set regardless.

EDIT: quick context tutorial

There are countless resources online to understand variable context in Python so I'm going to give a condensed explanation using examples.

Let's start with the explanation of context in Python. Context (or scope) is defined as the "space" where a variable or function is available for use. If a variable is defined in a given context, then any other variable or function may call on it afterwards. For example:

```
foo = 3
print foo
```

This would print `3`. However, this would fail

```
print foo
foo = 3
```

The reason being that although `foo` is in the right context, it has not yet been defined.

Now about your question which was something like "if the variables are global then what's the point of having a function", the second part of Python context is that nested functions inherit the previous context. So if I did:

```
foo = 3
def print_foo():
    print foo

print_foo()
```

Then this would print `3` since `foo` is in the same context as the function. Where would you use this?

This extends to more nesting of contexts. You could have functions within functions and still at each level the variables would be available to that level and below.

I hope this helps you understand context a little better however I oversimplified and excluded many important details so please take the time to read up on more Python context tutorials.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Maybe I formatted my code badly but `apiArray` is declared and i need it in that function.

Comment: apiArray is declared outside the scope of the function so it's global to the entire file, you don't need to pass it as an argument. The arguments to the function should only be what you are expecting to come from your URL parameters. Follow @ZekeDroid 's advice and it will work.

Comment: What should i have done instead to get that array into my function? I can't move the array inside the function because in the actual code it calls a function from another script on my system to populate it and I don't want this script to be called every time the function runs.

Comment: @FergalMoran @ZekeDroid, thanks, this has worked. I was under the impression that the variables in a function were separate and the only way to access a variable in a function was to pass it in as an argument. Is it different when you have `@route`?

Comment: @cross: You should go through [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) to familiarize yourself with how variables work in Python.

Comment: @cross: you definitely should go through the Python tutorial to understand about variable context. Regardless, this won't help you understand how the route functions work. The way to think about it is that whatever argument you require in a function with a route MUST be in the route as a parameter, otherwise it will always fail.

Comment: @BrenBarn I've used python lots - I'm really confused at the moment. I thought to get any variable into a function you had to pass it as a function? When did I make `apiArray` global? I know to you guys this may seam really obvious but I'm honesty really confused because in the past whenever I've written a function I'v had to pass it as an argument to get it into the function.

Comment: Ok, thank you ZekeDroid. So this is only happening because i had the `@route` function? I would usually have to pass the variable as a argument wouldn't I?

Comment: @cross - in python, if you declare a variable in a file outside of a class or function then that variable is available to every function in the file.

Comment: @FergalMoran Forgive me if this is a stupid question but what would the point in passing arguments to a function be then?

Comment: Well - in the case of a bottle route like about, the point would be to capture your URL parameters. In other cases it would be to pass data that was not global into the function.

I'm not trying to sound patronising here but I think you really need to read up a little bit on variable scoping in python (or any other language as the rules are broadly similar).

Comment: @cross: it's not a stupid question if you don't know the answer. It's just that regardless of how long you've been using Python for, this is a very common concept, the idea of context. I'll edit my answer to explain.

Comment: @cross: You might want to ask a separate question if you're confused about this, as it has nothing to do with `route`.  You pass arguments when you want to specify information that is (or may be) different on every call of the function.  If you use a global variable, the function will be accessing the same global variable on every call.

Comment: @ZekeDroid: Your example code will raise an `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: And thanks for the explanation. I guess I always thought that to use a variable in a function you HAD to pass it as an argument. I'm going to read up on this because I've done lots in python and I can't believe I've missed something apparently so simple.

Comment: @BrenBarn: you are absolutely right. It's because counter is a `scope` variable, it's not `global`. I wrote it too fast and had JS in my mind where integers are objects and so the reference would've worked. I used a bad example of scoping so I'm going to delete because I think it doesnt add anything to the discussion anyways. Thanks for pointing it out though.